# Converting an x86 TortoiseSVN plugin to x64

Tags: plugins, c#-3.0, tortoisesvn, 64-bit, x86-64

I'm trying to convert a 32bit TortoiseSVN-plugin (an IBugTraqProvider implementation) we've written so that It will work on TortoiseSVN x64; but I'm struggling with what I need to change to make it work. Are there any specific tools that would  help or does anyone know what types of things would need to be changed (references/IBugTraqProvider?)

Comment: Do you mean a plugin *for* Tortoise, or a Plugin that *uses* Tortoise?

Comment: Tortoise-Plugin i'll correct that messy english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to compile it for x64, and of course register it as an x64 dll (i.e., creating the registry entries in the x64 part of the registry).

You could check out [Gurtle](http://code.google.com/p/gurtle/) and see how it's done there.

Comment: I was a tad thrown off by gurtle as it uses a python installation script rather than the built in VS system.
I've previously compiled it for x64 but doe the IBugTraqProvider script need to change or the com reference? I'm not 100% sure how to register for x64.

Comment: As I said: you don't have to change anything besides compiling and registering it for x64. No changes in the COM interface or anything else. To register it for x64, either create an msi for x64, or create an x64 exe installer which registers it. Or provide a *.reg file with all the registry info needed and then apply that reg file on an x64 OS.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using the following...

```
%SystemRoot%\microsoft.net\Framework64\v2.0.50727\regasm.exe MIssues.dll /codebase
REG ADD HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{5870B3F1-8393-4C83-ACED-1D5E803A4F2B} /ve /d "My Plugin" /f
REG ADD "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{5870B3F1-8393-4C83-ACED-1D5E803A4F2B}\Implemented Categories\{3494FA92-B139-4730-9591-01135D5E7831}" /ve
```